# what are the different (spiritual/mental) effects of different yoga/meditation techniques

Tags: meditation-effects, yoga, cause-and-effect

from my experience aum-mantra meditation and physical yoga have altered my mental/spiritual state quicker and it's been sustained for longer in between practice sessions than just focusing on my breathing. The former have brought me much stronger states too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's some misunderstanding here.  Meditation isn't about producing effects. Its purpose is to prepare the mind for liberating insight.  The feelings of peace, joy, heightened awareness, etc. while undoubtably nice, are really just side effects.  There's no transactional relationship between practice and its fruits like there is between working out and getting in shape.  Meditation doesn't produce Buddhahood like jogging produces cardiovascular fitness.  Meditation brings you to the well, but insight is actually taking a drink.

You are certainly welcome to enjoy the bliss that meditation brings.  After all, you did earn it through the rigors of your practice.  But do not mistake these effects for the actual goal of the great way.  If you do, there is a very real risk of becoming a seeker of subtle pleasure all the while neglecting the cultivation of wisdom - the one true aim of practice.

Comment: thanks so much for the insight .One more question,  this wisdom you unlock I'm assuming comes from intuition and not (experience or study etc.)